# Case and accent insensitive matching of words in two files

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I got two **unquoted and single column** TSV files (exported from a database) with a few thousand people names and I need to find the names that appear in both files. Both files are `UTF-8`, `CRLF` terminated, and start with the BOM `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`.

A simple `join` or `comm` command could have done the trick but there are a few differences in the names:

```sh
# cat file1.tsv
A.  Einstein
Louis Pasteur 
Diego Armando Maradona
Isaac Newton
 Frava D’onä
D Rüge
Françoise Barré-Sinoussi
```

```sh
# cat file2.tsv
Diego Maradona
Albert Einstein
Francoise, BARRE  SINOUSSI
Louis Pasteur
frava d'ona
Marie-Louise Von FRANZ
Dimitri Rüge
```

The expected matches in `file2.tsv` would be:

```
Diego Maradona
Albert Einstein
Francoise, BARRE  SINOUSSI
Louis Pasteur
frava d'ona
Dimitri Rüge
```

---

I've wrote this `bash` `sed` `awk` `grep` script that dynamically generates a regex for matching the last names:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# U+0300 = 0xCC80 = 52352
# U+033F = 0xCCBF = 52415
# U+0340 = 0xCD80 = 52608
# U+036E = 0xCDAE = 52654

_COMBINING_CHARS_=()

for i in {52352..52415} {52608..52654}
do
    hex=$(printf %04X "$i")
    _COMBINING_CHARS_+=( "$(printf '\x'"${hex:0:2}"'\x'"${hex:2:2}")" )
done

_COMBINING_CHARS_ERE_=$(IFS='|'; printf %s "${_COMBINING_CHARS_[*]}")
```

```sh
# Function that removes the BOM, CRLF, and COMBINING characters:
sanitize() {
    LANG=C sed -E \
        -e $'1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' \
        -e $'s/\r$//' \
        -e "s/$_COMBINING_CHARS_ERE_//g" \
    -- "$@"
}
```

```sh
# Function that generates a regex for the _lastname_:
toERE() {
    awk '
        {
            if ( $0 ~ /,/) {
                n = split($0, a, ",");
                $0 = a[n];
            } else {
                $0 = $NF
            }
            sub("^[[:space]]+","");
            sub("[[:space]]+$","");
            gsub("[[:space:]-]+"," ");
        }

        {
            ere = ""
            sep = "";
            for ( nf = 1; nf <= NF; nf++ ) {
                n = split($nf, c, "");
                for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
                    ere = ere "[[=" c[i] "=]]"
                }
                ere = sep ere 
                sep = "[[:space:]-]+"
            }
            print ere "[[:space:]]*$"
        }
    ' < <(sanitize "$@")
}
```

```sh
grep -E -f <(toERE "$1") <(sanitize "$2")
```

---

Unfortunately, the result with the given input is:

```
grep: illegal byte sequence
```

UTF-8 multibyte characters seems to be the problem but I can't think of a way to handle it with `awk`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why did you remove the `regex` tag? I'm generating a regex with `awk` and it needs extending.

Comment: POSIX regex has no notion of "similarity". If you need fuzzy matches, you could use Python `regex` or other tools.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So the tag `regex` is POSIX only?

Comment: No, bash, awk, grep here imply this. GNU `grep` can be used with PCRE, but it won't help here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "_POSIX regex has no notion of "similarity"_". POSIX regex do have equivalence classes, which is a "similarity" notion. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>In the end I did the job with `ruby` but I post an `awk` solution nevertheless.</sup>

There was two problems:

- POSIX `[= =]` doesn't work for diacritic characters
- `awk` doesn't know about multi-byte characters

Working around that is possible by converting the input files to ASCII. `iconv` can do it somewhat accurately for Romanian characters, which is what I needed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

to_ascii() {
    case $(uname) in
    Darwin)
        iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8-MAC "$@" |
        iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE
        ;;
    Linux)
        iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE "$@"
        ;;
    esac |
    sed $'s/\r$//'
}
```

Now we just need to do a little normalization and find the perfect matches in the family names:

```sh
awk '
    {
        gsub("-+","-");
        gsub("\27+","\27");
        gsub("[.[:space:]]+"," ");
        sub("^[[:space:]]+","");
        sub("[[:space:]]+$","");
    }
    {
        if ($0 ~ /,/) {
            n = split($0,a,"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*");
            lastname = a[n];
        } else {
            lastname = $NF;
        }
        gsub("[-[:space:]]+"," ",lastname);
        lastname = tolower(lastname);
    }
    FNR == NR {
        keys[lastname] = $0;
        next;
    }
    {
        count = 0;
        for (n in keys) {
            if (n == lastname) {
                matches[++count] = keys[n]
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            print $0
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                print "\t" matches[i]
            }
        }
    }
' <(to_ascii "$2") <(to_ascii "$1")
```

output

```
A Einstein
    Albert Einstein
Louis Pasteur
    Louis Pasteur
Diego Armando Maradona
    Diego Maradona
Frava D'ona
    frava d'ona
D Ruge
    Dimitri Ruge
Francoise Barre-Sinoussi
    Francoise, BARRE SINOUSSI
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `agrep`? `man agrep`: *agrep - search a file for a string or regular expression, with approximate matching capabilities*. It's not perfect like we will see:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line
do 
    echo -n "$line: "
    agrep -B -y  "$line" file1
done < file2
```

Output:

```
Diego A. Maradona: agrep: 1 word matches within 6 errors
Maradona, Diego Armando
Albert Einstein: agrep: 1 word matches within 5 errors
A. Einstein
Louis Pasteur: Louis Pasteur
frava dona: agrep: 2 words match within 4 errors
Maradona, Diego Armando
Fräva Dona
```

Nice sample as we can already see a problem in the last three lines.

Comment: Nice idea. I don't have it but I'll give it a try later

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting the following trick:

```
 cat file1.csv file1.csv | sort | uniq -d
```

#### Explanation

`cat file1.csv file1.csv` combine bot files one after the other

`sort`                    put similar lines together

`uniq -d`                 print only line that have duplicates

Comment: Thanks @DudiBoy. That's the first thing that I tried when I was given the task, but it doesn't work with the inconsistencies that I have in the two files. See the expected output that I added in the question.